# How to track changes with Envers so on child update the current version of the parent is linked to the current version of the child with the changes?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-envers

Let's say we have an versioned entity Book.
The book has a property which is also a versioned entity Author.

```
Author author = new Author();
author.setName("foo");
save(author);


Book book = new Book();
book.setAuthor(author);
save(book);
```

Now if I change the author's name eg

```
author.setName("bar");
```

I want "bar" to be seen from the version of Book as of this hour. eg

```
Book book = getRevForHour(Book.class, LocalDateTime.now());

if (book.getAuthor().getName() == "bar") {
    System.out.println("got what I wanted");
} else {
    System.out.println("didn't get what I wanted");
}
```

But right now I'm getting "foo" which is the value the Author had as of the last rev creation for Book.

Is there a way to trigger a cascade of rev creations upwards to all entities? Or is there a better way to get such historic data?

edit:

I ended up adding a column "last_update" to all entities and entirely manually ended up propagating changes upwards whenever an entity was altered. Changing the value in lastUpdate then triggered envers to create a new version.